# delete line from StringIO

Tags: python, string

I have a data from `dataframe` inside of `buffer` of `StringIO` like this

```py
buf = StringIO()
df.to_csv(buf, sep='\t', na_rep='\\N', index=False, header=False)
buf.seek(0)
```

I'm looping lines in buffer

```py
for row in buf:
```

And I would like to delete the line from buffer if some condition is true like

```py
    if len(row) > 5:
        buf.remove(row)
```

How could I accomplish this?

Comment: Stream objects do not support a remove method. Why not filter the unwanted row before writing to the stream?

Comment: If about terminal output, it's good to `buf.write('\b')` to backspace.

Comment: In general, modifying the middle of streams is not worth the trouble. Just create a new stream that is modified.